# Nuget install package with wildcard version

Tags: nuget

How to achieve package reference with wildcard version by using install-package in visual studio 2017? 
Example line :

> PackageReference Include="somePackage" Version="*"

When I try

> Install-Package somePackage -Version *

I get error:

> Install-Package : Failed to parse the input of Version parameter: * to
>   a valid Semantic version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately install-package command does not support a wild card version. But if you have a .NET Core based project then you can use the `dotnet.exe add package package_name --version *` command from the developer command prompt.

How to check if your project is .NET Core based -

1. Right click on the project in VS and see if there is an option `Edit project_name.csproj`

If your project is .NET Core based -

1. Launch developer command prompt from the start bar
2. cd project_directory
3. `dotnet add package package_name --version *`

Please note that having a `*` in a package reference is potentially dangerous as it will always get you the latest version which can bring in breaking changes.

Comment: Always getting latest major version isn't a good idea. It is wise to zero in on a major version within which you want to wildcard. Nice answer. Thanks.

Comment: Can you use wildcards in package name as well?

Answer (score 2):

`dotnet add package` does not support neither pre-releases nor wildcards, see open issues:

- https://github.com/nuget/home/issues/4699
- https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/912

Comment: thanks for the answer but it isn't actually addressing the original question. Please add more to your post so that it is an answer to the question asked as opposed to using answers to comment on other answers. Also, the links you provided are not specifying that `dotnet add package` doesn't support wildcards. 1.0.0-rc < 1.0.0 and therefore doesn't satisfy the 1.0.* range specification.